# Reject route not translated in JMSi18nRoutingBundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization

Im using this bundle in my site with Symfony2 and there are some problems with not translated routes.

For example:

    `http://en.site.com/home -> is correct and it works.
    -http://es.site.com/inicio -> is correct and it works.`

Now the problem is here, combining both like:

    `-es.site.com/home -> not correct but it works.
    -en.site.com/inicio -> not correct but it works.`

The config.yml is:

    `jms_i18n_routing:
        default_locale: %locale%
        locales: %languages%
        strategy: custom`

NOTE: I have try the strategy: prefix_except_default but I have the same problem.

I dont know all the strategies avaliable for this.

Thanks to all.

Comment: The url are the same, where do you expect to see a difference when your urls got none ?

Answer (score 0):

if I request the site with the english lenguaje and with the spanish param the bundle has to throw an 404 error because that route doesnt exists in the routes translated file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was setting up the parameter redirect_to_host to true to redirect to the correct locale using the page as a reference, or false to show a 406 error.